# calculate the two dimensional integral $\int_B x^2-y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to calculate the two dimensional integral \begin{equation*}\int_B x^2-y^2\end{equation*} Where $B$ is the area bounded by \begin{equation*}xy=1,y=0,x=y,x^2-y^2=1\end{equation*}
I have been suggested to try and substitute $u=x^2-y^2,v=xy$ but I'm having a hard time finding the set on which I should parametrise. 

Can anyone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u = x^2-y^2, v = xy$. The conditions $xy = 1 \to v = 1, y = 0 \to xy = 0 \to v = 0, x = y \to x^2 = y^2 \to x^2-y^2 = 0 \to u = 0$. Thus you integrate over $B': u = 0, u = 1, v = 0, v = 1 \to I =\displaystyle \int_{B'} u\dfrac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}dudv$. Don't forget to calculuate the "Jacobian"...

Comment: Is $dxdy$ equal to $dudv$?